# What should be the max_connection for 48 core PROCESSORS and 256 gb RAM?

Tags: mysql

What should be the max_connection for 48 core PROCESSORS and 256 gb RAM ?

Comment: The upper limit is 100,000 for many current versions of MySQL and MariaDB.  Many people are successful with this formula of max_connections = max_used_connections * 1.1 - for a 10% growth planned.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections'; will reveal highest concurrent connections since instance started.  You might want to check this after 7 days of uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `max_connections = 2000`.  Keep an eye on the `STATUS` `Max_used_connections` for a week.  If that approaches `max_connections`, then raise the limit.  If not, leave it at 2000 and move on to other concerns.

Set `thread_cache_size` to one-quarter of `max_connections`.

Neither of these settings matters much.  The main downside risk is getting denied a connection due to "too many connections".